# word meaning "beyond the letter of the law"

Tags: single-word-requests

The words "extralegal," or "extrajudicial" mean outside the law in a negative way-illegal actions not sanctioned by law. But what is a word for a practice not mandated by law, but praiseworthy nonetheless. In Judaic Law, for instance, there is an entire tract dedicated to enumerating practices that are not required, but are adhered to by the pious.

Comment: If you do something *not mandated by law, but praiseworthy nonetheless*, you might say you're adopting/following ***best practice*** (or ***recommended practice***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethical is the first word that comes to mind--a quick thesaurus check using it gave a great list of other words that fit the profile.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ethical?s=t

Comment: Nah, **ethics** are specifically concerned with what is _good_ and necessary for all of us to adhere to in order to maintain a society whose social ethos justifies the constraints of the expectations of the people – e.g., generally treating people equally, abhorring abuse/murder/etc, and so on.  ("**Normative ethics**" is the branch that most people think of re: evaluating "what's right" to do in a challenging situation.)   Note also that _morals_ are separate and orthogonal to _ethics_.  In short, ethics is more about the things you gotta do, morals are about what you think you should be.

Comment: .. and @R.Block was specifically asking about praiseworthy deeds _beyond_ those strictly required, so ethical considerations are actually lie on the other side of that divide.  Cheers

Comment: As I understand the question, R. block was asking for what isn't required by law, "But what is a word for a practice not mandated by law, but praiseworthy nonetheless." I would argue ethical behavior is praiseworthy--though I'm sure some may disagree. Still the link for synonyms for "ethical" has more options for those who don't think ethical behavior is praiseworthy.

Comment: – But the absence of ethical behavior is a marked _shortcoming_, a fundamental insufficiency in the agent; the question is about stuff going _beyond_ the law – as in, the law needs to be sufficiently fulfilled before you even get in the door.   While it may be possible to be so ethically pure that one can act well beyond expectation, but that's just a set-intersection with the set of all acts beyond expectation; so while being ethical may be _necessary_ to fulfill the requirements of good conduct, it is not in itself necessarily always _sufficient_.  I _like_ this question! Cheers

Comment: Art imitating life: is it unethical to downvote an answer when you post a competing answer? Is that a shortcoming? Is not using those tactics praiseworthy by those aware of their use? Personally, I'd praise someone if they didn't do those sorts of things--even though they are not prohibited by the rules and I would say that is ethical behavior.

Comment: Of course it's not wrong to downvote an answer if you have a competing idea!  It's the only way for the ecosystem to regulate itself like it's meant to :)  Voting down an answer on its merits has exactly **nothing** to do with being ethical; if anything, withholding the useful truths in the unused criticism _would_ be unethical, if one meant to adhere to the first principles of the site.  Feelings about popularity don't have anything to do with the legitimacy of a contribution — life will be _awful_ if one subjects oneself to living that way!

Comment: Conflicts or interest are rarely ethical--I write rarely as most cannot discern their own motives.They usually get it wrong and latch positive assertions onto the pettiest of aims. And in a semantical argument, it would be pretty absurd to assume some objective measure of truth.

Comment: It's not a conflict of interest — we are comparing semantically-differing proposals and yours is, frankly, quite clearly logically insufficient to fulfill the request.  The popularity contest that you seem to be worried about is in no way germane to an analysis of the question.  I suggest perhaps you might read up on "Normative Ethics", a branch which I think will shed some light on nuances you seem not quite to be appreciating — no offense, but I have at least studied at the college level on just this.  ** OK, I'm done with this, too chatty already, but completeness matters too. Cheers.

Comment: To quote Jeff Bridges great character, "That's just like you opinion, man." IE. It's a semantical debate, not an objective one. My interpretation of ethics isn't imbued with a course you took in college, but has its own influences that don't mesh with yours. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

> enumerating practices that are not required, but are adhered to by the pious

You could say that the pious are following the [spirit or intent of the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law) rather than just the literal interpretation.

> a practice not mandated by law, but praiseworthy nonetheless

Doing something not mandated but praiseworthy could be going [above and beyond](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/above-and-beyond) your duty. Though it might be hard to apply to most people without confusing the reader whether the actions are outside the *law* or their *normal duties*, unless they are part of the legal system (judges, police etc.)

Answer (score 0):

"**Supererogation**" is the technical term for the class of actions that go “beyond the call of duty.” Roughly speaking, supererogatory acts are morally good although not (strictly) required.

—sourced from http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supererogation, a fascinating entry on distinctions between values and duties, for example; cheers.

Comment: Also, "supererogatory" sounds dirty, so now I will definitely make a point of trying to use it.